# Understanding the relationship between the covariant and contravarient basis in Euclidean space using traditional matricies

Tags: matrices, tensors, index-notation

For a contravariant basis vector in ${\Bbb R}^n$ that is defined using a covariant basis vector ${\bf Z}_j$ in ${\Bbb R}^n$ in terms of the contravarient metric tensor as:

$${\bf Z}^i = Z^{ij}{\bf Z}_j$$

where the contravariant metric tensor $Z^{ij}$ is defined as the inverse of the covariant metric tensor $Z_{ij} = {\bf Z}_i\cdot{\bf Z}_j$, how does one reach the conclusion that the covariant basis is also the inverse of the contravarient basis, or ${\bf Z}^i\cdot{\bf Z}_j = {\delta}^{i}_{j}$?

As I'm trying to adapt my understanding of this relationship to more traditional matrix operations, I'm getting the following for the covarient and contravariant metric tensor relationship, treating the collection of $n$ covariant basis vectors ${\bf Z}_i$ as the matrix $A$ in ${\Bbb R}^n$, the $n$ contravariant basis vectors as the matrix $A^{-1}$ in ${\Bbb R}^n$, and the covariant metric tensor as the matrix $A^tA$ with it's corresponding inverse as the contravariant metric tensor:

$$(A^tA)^{-1}(A^tA) = I$$

The trouble I run into is that using the initial definition of the contravariant basis as ${\bf Z}^i = Z^{ij}{\bf Z}_j$, where $Z^{ij}$ is the same as $(A^tA)^{-1}$ and the $n$ vectors ${\bf Z}_j$ in ${\Bbb R}^n$ form $A$, I believe we would end up with a matrix operation like:

$$(A^tA)^{-1}A = A^{-1}$$

in order to obtain the contravariant basis $A^{-1}$, but that is not the correct relationship. If I changed ${\bf Z}_j$ to $A^t$ then

$$(A^tA)^{-1}A^t = A^{-1}$$

does work, but I don't see how ${\bf Z}^i = Z^{ij}{\bf Z}_j$ indicates I should transpose the matrix $A$ into $A^t$. How should I think about this relationship if I was to write it out using traditional matrix operations rather than index/tensor notation?

Comment: Why do you think you can just replace $\mathbf Z^i$ and $\mathbf Z_j$ with square matrices?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff They are vector quantities, so in a $R^{n}$ space all the vectors that form either the covariant or contravariant basis should be able to form a square $n \times n$ matrix, correct?  Or am I not understanding how ${\bf Z}^{i}$ and ${\bf Z}_{j}$ work?

Comment: You should specify in your question that you are working in $\mathbb R^n$ and that the $i^{\text{th}}$ column of $A$ is $\mathbf Z_i$. I think the issue you're having then is keeping track of rows and columns; for instance $\mathbf Z^i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ **row** of $A^{-1}$. In $Z^{ij}\mathbf Z_j$, you are **not** applying a matrix to a column vector, which would be something like $Z^{kl}(\mathbf Z_j)_l$. You are instead **forming a linear combination of columns**. If you account for this correctly, you will see that $(A^tA)^{-1}A^t = A^{-1}$ is indeed the correct equation.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Thank you for the clarification. When you say that $Z^{ij}{\bf Z}_j$ is forming a "linear combination of columns" which I'm assuming would be the $j$ columns of $Z^{ij}$, isn't that the same thing as $Ax = b$, where the components of the vector $x$ create a linear combination of the columns of $A$ to create the vector $b$? If that is the case, then why isn't the aforementioned operation of $Z^{ij}{\bf Z}_j$ considered the same as applying a matrix to a vector where $Z^{ij}$ is a matrix and each $j$ element of ${\bf Z}_j$ is a column vector?

Comment: Applying a matrix $M$ to a vector $v$ looks like $M^i_jv^j$ where $v^j$ are the **components** of $v$. $\mathbf Z_i$ are not **components** of a vector, they **are vectors**.

Comment: Consider that $A^i_j = (\mathbf Z_j)^i$, the $i$th component of the vector $\mathbf Z_j$. Then $Z^{ij}\mathbf Z_j = Z^{ij}A^k_j = Z^{ij}(A^t)^j_k$, where in the last expression $j$ is still summed.